# How to add freeze frame to a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to freeze some frames in a video so that it gives a buffering video type look. Also the audio should freeze with the video.

Answer (score 2):

Assume there are three pauses of 3 seconds each at 5s, 12s and 20s of the original video. Here's the basic form of the command,

`ffmpeg -i in -vf "setpts='PTS-STARTPTS + gte(T,5)*(3/TB) + gte(T,12)*(3/TB) + gte(T,20)*(3/TB)'" -af "asetpts='PTS-STARTPTS + gte(T,5)*(3/TB) + gte(T,12)*(3/TB) + gte(T,20)*(3/TB)',aresample=async=1:first_pts=0" -vsync cfr out`

Comment: I get the following error while running the command:

ffmpeg -i abc.avi -vf "setpts='PTS-STARTPTS + gte(t,5)*(3/TB) + gte(t,12)*(3/TB) + gte(t,20)*(3/TB)'" -af "asetpts='PTS-STARTPTS + gte(t,5)*(3/TB) + gte(t,12)*(3/TB) + gte(t,20)*(3/TB)',aresample=async=1:first_pts=0" -vsync crf out.avi


**error**: Expected number for vsync but found: crf
if I add -vsync 0, then
**error**: Unable to find a suitable output format for 'crf'

Comment: It's not `crf`, See answer.

Comment: thanks.. but there is still some error. I have posted it in the answer below.

Comment: Your command is missing the * in `gte(t,5)*(3/TB)` and in other expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The code by @gyan didn't work out for me, I found another (longer) way to do it:

I extracted the audio file from the video first using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -ab 128 audio.mp3
```

then combined them together with an offset:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "input.mp4" -itsoffset 3 -i "input_audio.wav" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Did you add the `*`?

Comment: **yes I did try your code, but it shows error **:       ffmpeg -i sb.mp4 -vf "setpts='PTS-STARTPTS + gte(t,5)*(3/TB) + gte(t,12)*(3/TB) + gte(t,20)*(3/TB)'" -af " asetpts='PTS-STARTPTS + gte(t,5)*(3/TB) + gte(t,12)*(3/TB) + gte(t,20)*(3/TB)',aresample=async=1:first_pts=0" -vsync cfr  outsb.mp4